# "Numbers on a blackboard"-type puzzles

Tags: feature-request, tags, tag-synonyms

This question was tagged [blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackboard): [Numbers on the blackboard: From 2-2015 to 1-2014](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23227/numbers-on-the-blackboard-from-2-2015-to-1-2014)

Currently, that is the only question under this tag, but these questions would also fit under what I think the intention of the tag is:

- [Ten numbers on a blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/7862/ten-numbers-on-a-blackboard)
- [Numbers on a Blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16729/numbers-on-a-blackboard)
- [The last number on the blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23161/the-last-number-on-the-blackboard)
- [Triangle of numbers on a blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23204/triangle-of-numbers-on-a-blackboard)

This type of problem is characterized by a set of numbers being written on a blackboard, and operations being used to change the numbers. The solution usually involves an invariant or monovariant of the system. As [xnor commented](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23204/triangle-of-numbers-on-a-blackboard#comment71225_23205):

> I want to point out the general idea here that also solves [this problem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/7862/4551): apply a transformation to the numbers so that the combining operation on the transformed numbers is commutative and associative.

Two of the questions are also tagged [reachability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reachability): "A puzzle on a discrete system where one has to decide whether a certain system state can be reached through a finite number of steps." This seems like the closest tag we have currently, but it is broader than the category of "blackboard questions".

Should [blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackboard) be a tag of its own, a synonym of [reachability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reachability), or neither?

Comment: Blackboard should not a synonym of reachability, since the two categories can't be used interchangeably.

Comment: What _is_ a blackboard puzzle?

Comment: @Emrakil: A puzzle in which various numbers are written on a board, and they can be erase and replaced with other numbers based on various rules; the goal is to reach a certain point or prove that it's impossible.

Comment: @MikeEarnest I was under the impression that a non-notable subset of a category of puzzles can be made a synonym of the larger category. For example, [tag:party-security] is a synonym of [tag:password], and [tag:minimum-solve] is a synonym of [tag:optimization]. In both of these cases, the synonym is a subset of the main tag, but they aren't interchangeable.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I don't think they should be synonyms. We can leave the [blackboard](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/blackboard) tag as it is, because there are a few such questions and more might turn up in the future.

Yes, it is a subset of [reachability](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/reachability) but how is that a problem? There are reachability questions that do not involve a blackboard also. And [number-theory](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/number-theory) is a subset of [math](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/math) and both are very popular.